# Creating a tibble and randomization

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a tibble with ID (`iter`) and randomly generated data.

```
   iter data
  <int> <list>
1     1 <dbl [5]>
2     2 <dbl [5]>
3     3 <dbl [5]>
```

I tried two types of codes and only one of them gives the expected result, but I am not sure why it is, because the only difference is generating data inside `tibble()` or not.

```
iter <- 2 ; n <- 5 ; mu <- 1
gen_data <- function(x){  # randomly draw from Exponential function
    return(rexp(n, rate=1/mu))
}

# Works (different values each time)
data <- lapply(1:iter, gen_data)
tibble(iter = 1:iter,
             data = data) %>% unnest(data)

# Doesn't work (+ there is a warning)
tibble(iter = 1:iter,
             data = lapply(1:iter, gen_data)) %>% unnest(data)
```

Comment: see `?tibble`: "tibble() builds columns sequentially. When defining a column, you can refer to columns created earlier in the call. Only columns of length one are recycled." In the second example, the `iter` refers to the `iter` column (1:2) you just created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `lapply()` in the second expample that doesn't work, you need to be referencing `iter` only by it's name instead of trying to re-build a vector.

```
tibble(iter = 1:iter,
       data = lapply(iter, gen_data)) %>% unnest(data)
```

This is because `tibble()` is looking for variables by name within it's context and `iter` already exists there as `c(1,2)`. The warning comes from you passing two element to `:` which complains, then moves ahead using the first element.